# implicty error about cs0029 in C# Machine Learning

Tags: c#, .net, machine-learning

When i do the ML.DOTNET practice through Microsoft Docs presented exercise, I found error that about CS0029
The total code is like that

```
using System;
using System.IO;
using Microsoft.ML;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using Microsoft.ML.TimeSeries;
namespace ProductSalesAnomalyDetection
{
    class Program
    {
        static readonly string _dataPath = Path.Combine(Environment.CurrentDirectory, "Data", "phone-calls.csv");

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            MLContext mlContext = new MLContext();

            IDataView dataView = mlContext.Data.LoadFromTextFile<PhoneCallsData>(path: _dataPath, hasHeader: true, separatorChar: ',');

            int period = DetectPeriod(mlContext, dataView);

            DetectAnomaly(mlContext, dataView, period);
        }

        static void DetectPeriod(MLContext mlContext, IDataView phoneCalls)
        {
            int period = mlContext.AnomalyDetection.DetectSeasonality(phoneCalls, nameof(PhoneCallsData.value));

            Console.WriteLine("Period of the series is: {0}.", period);
        }

        static void DetectAnomaly(MLContext mlContext, IDataView phoneCalls, int period)
        {
            var options = new SrCnnEntireAnomalyDetectorOptions()
            {
                Threshold = 0.3,
                Sensitivity = 64.0,
                DetectMode = SrCnnDetectMode.AnomalyAndMargin,
                Period = period,
            };

            var outputDataView = mlContext.AnomalyDetection.DetectEntireAnomalyBySrCnn(phoneCalls, nameof(PhoneCallsPrediction.Prediction), nameof(PhoneCallsData.value), options);

            var predictions = mlContext.Data.CreateEnumerable<PhoneCallsPrediction>(
                outputDataView, reuseRowObject: false);

            Console.WriteLine("Index\tData\tAnomaly\tAnomalyScore\tMag\tExpectedValue\tBoundaryUnit\tUpperBoundary\tLowerBoundary");

            var index = 0;

            foreach (var p in predictions)
            {
                if (p.Prediction[0] == 1)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("{0},{1},{2},{3},{4}  <-- alert is on, detecte anomaly", index,
                        p.Prediction[0], p.Prediction[3], p.Prediction[5], p.Prediction[6]);
                }
                else
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("{0},{1},{2},{3},{4}", index,
                        p.Prediction[0], p.Prediction[3], p.Prediction[5], p.Prediction[6]);
                }
                ++index;

            }

            Console.WriteLine("");



        }


    }
}
```

the error section is in Main method

```
int period = DetectPeriod(mlContext, dataView);
```

and the error is cannot implicitly convert type 'void' to 'int'.

I just follow the presented code but it looks like some error on it.
Maybe I put the wrong code in wrong place but I try to follow their instruction strictly.
Also It will be very thankful if you tell me about difference between JAVA and C# implicitly convert type 'void' to 'int'.
Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`static void DetectPeriod(MLContext mlContext, IDataView phoneCalls)` says that `DetectPeriod()` doesn't return anything. You're then trying to assign that non-existent return value to `int period`.

You need to change the definition to returning `int`, and then actually `return` an `int` value.

```
static int DetectPeriod(MLContext mlContext, IDataView phoneCalls)
  {
      int period = mlContext.AnomalyDetection.DetectSeasonality(phoneCalls, nameof(PhoneCallsData.value));

      Console.WriteLine("Period of the series is: {0}.", period);
      return period;
  }
```